# Initialize subclasses after @PostConstruct

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm using the Context Dependency Injection CDI 1.1 framework from JavaEE 7, within the WildFly 8.2 application server

I want to initialize subclasses after a `@PostConstruct` of the super class

So I do somthing like that

```
// case 1: it's working but it's not simple to understand

public class A {

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("A");
        afterInit();
    }

    protected void afterInit() {}

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void afterInit() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}


public class C extends B {

    @Override
    protected void afterInit() {
        super.afterInit();
        System.out.println("C");
    }

}
```

So the `init()` method will print A, B, C in this order

It would be fine to have a `@AfterPostconstruct` annotation that would do the same but I don't find out

```
// case 2: dream code

public class A {

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @AfterPostConstruct  // pseudocode
    protected void afterInitB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}


public class C extends B {

    @AfterPostConstruct // pseudocode
    protected void afterInitC() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

}
```

I try by overriding `init()` but it doesn't work (`init()` is not called by the container)

```
// case 3 : code that is not working but it would be better than case 1

public class A {

    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }

}

public class B extends A {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
        System.out.println("B");
    }

}


public class C extends B {

    @Override
    protected void init() {
        super.init();
        System.out.println("C");
    }

}
```

is there a better (simplier) way to initialize subclasses after `@PostConstruct` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to section *Invocation Order of Interceptors Declared on the Target Class* of the [JSR 318 - Interceptors 1.2](https://java.net/downloads/interceptors-spec/interceptor-1-2-mrel.pdf) (that applies to CDI 1.1 as well) specification:

> Interceptor methods declared on the target class or its superclasses
>   are invoked in the following order:
>
> - If a target class has superclasses, any interceptor methods defined on those superclasses are invoked, most general superclass first.
> - The interceptor method, if any, on the target class itself is invoked.
>
> If an interceptor method is overridden by another method (regardless
>   of whether that method is itself an interceptor method), it will not
>   be invoked.

So in your use case, you can write:

```
public class A {

    @PostConstruct
    private void initA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

public class B extends A {

    @PostConstruct
    private void initB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

public class C extends B {

    @PostConstruct
    private void initC() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }
}
```

And get printed: A, B, C in that order.